# org.json.simple. add header node

Tags: java, json

I'm using org.json.simple library and I have a json which looks like below

```
[
  {
    "lastName": "abc",
    "firstName": "def",
    "email": "abc@test.com",
    
  },
 {
    "lastName": "xyz",
    "firstName": "pqr",
    "email": "xyz@test.com",
    
  }
]
```

I need to add a header node. for example .. it should look like below. How to add "users" ??

```
 {
    "users" :
     [
      {
        "lastName": "abc",
        "firstName": "def",
        "email": "abc@test.com",
    
      },
     {
        "lastName": "xyz",
        "firstName": "pqr",
        "email": "xyz@test.com",
    
      }
     ]
   }
```

I already have org.json.simple.JSONObject for the above json..now I just need to add "users" at the top of json.

Comment: Your example json (2nd one) is invalid. An array should look like: `[{}, {}, ...]` where `{}` represents an object. What you can achieve is `{ "users": [{}, {}, {}, ...] }` shape.

Comment: Oh yeah.. just realized..  Will edit my question. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 1):

Put you existing array in to a new object.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) parser.parse("[{\"lastName\": \"abc\", \"firstName\": \"def\", \"email\": \"abc@test.com\" }, { \"lastName\": \"xyz\", \"firstName\": \"pqr\", \"email\": \"xyz@test.com\" }]");
System.out.println(arr); // First Json object (arr)

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("users", arr);

System.out.println(obj); // Second Json object
```